# How to sniff PostgreSQL network traffic?

Tags: postgresql, packet-sniffers

I want to see what my PostgreSQL database server (`postgres`) is sending in response to my client (a Ruby application server using the pg gem). Both the server & client are running locally, and their connection is unencrypted.

Answer (score 4):

Use [tcpdump](https://www.tcpdump.org/) to display packets sent between your client & server.

How? Enter the following command in Terminal on macOS:

```
sudo tcpdump -A -i any port 5432
```

Then, trigger your application server (for example, by sending it a curl request from another Terminal window) to send a command to `postgres`.

Finally, view the output of tcpdump.

Note: tcpdump doesn't show packets sent between `psql` & `postgres` since they communicate over a Unix domain socket. See: [Can I monitor a local unix domain socket like tcpdump?](https://superuser.com/q/484671/59284)

Answer (score 1):

Since `tcpdump` is already mentioned, I'd want to list another tool that can be used for this purpose with a less verbose output: [ngrep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ngrep)

Usage:

```
ngrep -d lo port 5432
```

`lo` is the network interface to listen to. This can be found out using `ifconfig`. `port 5432` is the [pcap filter](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html).

This can also be used to search for specific SQL statements if the aim is to capture SQL statements submitted by your application. For a detailed explanation, refer [here](http://techmango.org/2019/07/11/sniff-postgresql-traffic/).